# Error in send response to Browser with Socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am currently writing a simple proxy server that is like interface between my browser (Firefox or chrome) and web server, i set Firefox to send request to specific port (7777) and i listen to this port for getting request and send to internet for getting response.

For sending and receiving i using async socket sending request to web server , i have a problem for sending response to Firefox
since web server getting response of one request in multi part(8Kb) i send each part of response to browser immediately.
Now when i send the first part of my request that contain header information i have n't problem 
but when i want send the rest of my request that is GZip my browser raise this exception

FireFox : **Content Encoding Error** 
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.

Chrome : Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

**But when i put sleep(1000) in sendcallback it work correctly**

```
private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        SendStateObject Result = (SendStateObject)ar.AsyncState;

        int ByteSend = Result.WorkSocket.EndSend(ar);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

what is Problem ?
thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

It could be a race condition, because you're using asynchronous sockets.
Please take a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx